# how to get facebook friend list with emails through new graph api, v2.5?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to fetch the friend list using the code below

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMyFriendsRequest(
                token,
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONArrayCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONArray array, GraphResponse response) {
                        // Insert your code here
                    }
                });
        request.executeAsync();
    }
```

The response returned after code execution is

```
{Response:  responseCode: 200, graphObject: {"data":[],"summary":{"total_count":461}}, error: null}
```

Persmission to `access friends` and `public profile` is granted on login time.
How can i fetch my friend list and their public emails/ facebook emails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recive your friends list using graph-api call

```
/* make the API call */
new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/me/friends",
    null,
    HttpMethod.GET,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            /* handle the result */
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

But the limitation is

1. api required access token with user_friends permission
2. only return friends who are also given access permission to the same app you are
   using

.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/user/friends

Answer (score 3):

You'll only receive the friends whcih are also using your app, see

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

> `/me/friends` returns the user's friends who are also using your app
>   In v2.0, the friends API endpoint returns the list of a person's friends who are also using your app. In v1.0, the response included all of a person's friends.

And, **no**, there is no workaround in case you wanted to ask.